# My site doesn't look correct on different resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just started learning HTML/CSS/JS 2 days ago and today I made a little tool for personal use.
I made it on computer with a 1980 x 1080 resolution but on other resolutions it doesn't look right.

What I made is a little tool which basically allows me to put a band and the band's genre into an input field and then add it to a list.
Everything looks fine on different resolutions except for when I add a band to the list.
The text that's supposed to go into the border goes all the way to the right side of the screen and the border becomes just a tiny square.

Another question I had, which I might aswell ask in here:
I would like to add a function where I can click one of the bands I added to the list, then highlight the band I clicked, and remove it by clicking a remove button.
But I have no clue where to start.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Bands I Like</h2>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" id = "Item" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div id="button">Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="list"></div>

        <ol class = "Header">
            <li>Band // Genre</li>
        </ol>
        <br/>
        <ol class ="Bands">

        </ol>


    </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.Header {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.Header {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: 4px 20px;
    padding:0.4em;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}

.Bands li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;


}

.Bands li {
    background: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 4px 750px;
    padding:0.4em;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    //text-align:center;
}



h2 {
    font-family:arial;
    color:white;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}

#button{
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:70px;
    background-color:grey;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
}

.list {
    font-family:garamond;
    color:#cc0000;
}

body {
    background-image: url("http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/027/d/e/sphere_of_doom_by_crackoala-d386se9.png");
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
$('.Bands').append('<li>'+$('#Item').val()+'</li>');
    $('#Item').val("");
});
$('.Bands').sortable();
});
```

You can find all my code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mLkcr501/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `margin: 4px 750px;` What did you expect would happen?

Comment: I've tried 10px,5px,50px etc, nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your CSS was bumping it to the right.

```
margin: 4px 750px;
```

Then just needed to float the links left so the border thingy covered them:

```
.bands{
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mLkcr501/1/

-Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

you must use mediaquery to ajust the size on diferent resolutions.

```
@media (max-width: 640px){
    'here contains the class or ids'{width:100%; float: left;}
    .greyBox2{display:none;}
    .text{width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 17px;}
}
```